# Regex matching and grouping

Tags: regex

Need to parse the following string into groups:

```
September 6, 2015 8:00 pm PDT<br />        Foobar1: This may be a string or just some text.<br />        Foo Bar 2: Some other text<br />        Foo_Bar3: This could be anyting<br />        foobar4: Who knows<br />        Foobar5: more text (text)<br />        Foo bar6: There could be more<br />
```

The constants are the newline tags and the colon.  These will essentially be key/values, foobar being the key before the colon and the text on the right of the colon being the value.  There will be no telling how many key/value groups that there will be in the string.

This is as far as I've been able to get:

```
(?<Key>>.*:).*:.*(?<Value>:.*<)
```

but it matches from the first > to the last <, no groupings in between.  I can pull the 
 tags out in code.  Thanks in advance for looking.

Comment: What about the leading timestamp?

Comment: Actually no, forgot to mention that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is always a new line after the time stamp this should work:

```
(?<=<br\s/>)([^:]*?):(.*?)<br\s/>
```

To get the groups out of this for each match:

```
        string pattern = @"(?<=<br\s/>)(?'key'[^:]*?):(?'value'.*?)<br\s/>"; 
        string input = "September 6, 2015 8:00 pm PDT<br />        Foobar1: This may be a string or just some text.<br />        Foo Bar 2: Some other text<br />        Foo_Bar3: This could be anyting<br />        foobar4: Who knows<br />        Foobar5: more text (text)<br />        Foo bar6: There could be more<br />"; 
        MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(input, pattern); 
        for (int i = 0; i < matches.Count; i++) 
        {
            string key = matches[i].Groups["key"].ToString();
            string value = matches[i].Groups["value"].ToString();
        }
```

Comment: That does the groupings but I need a name to pull the group out in code (the <Key> and <Value> )

`string pattern = @"(?<=<br\s/>)([^:]*?):(.*?)<br\s/>";
string input = dataList;
MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(input, pattern);
for (int i = 0; i < matches.Count; i++)
{
string a = matches[i].("key").Groups.ToString();
string b...   
}`

I apologize if this is not displaying correctly

Comment: I've edited the answer, is that more in line with what you require?

Comment: That's perfect!  Thank you so much.